# IOException The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process when using XDocument

Tags: c#, xml, ioexception

I keep getting an IOException that it cannot access the file because it's being used by another process.  What i'm trying to do is that everytime the file i'm looking at is changed.. it's sending it as an array through TCP/IP.  i couldn't find any way of closing the XDocument and just don't know how to fix this error... i google'd and still couldn't find anything.  any help would be grateful

edit: i found other solutions with filereader and other things.. but it seems different when using xdocument

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

//filesystemwatcher
using System.IO;

//tcpip server
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;

//XML
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ChampSelect_FileWatcher
{
    class Program
    {
        //TCP IP variables
        public static Int32 port;
        public static IPAddress localAddr;
        public static TcpListener server;
        public static TcpClient client;
        public static NetworkStream stream;
        public static XDocument doc;


        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //LOAD XML FILE
            doc = XDocument.Load("C:/Trio Scripts/example.xml");

            //OBSERVE FILE
            FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
            watcher.Path = @"C:\Trio Scripts";
            watcher.Filter = "example.xml";

            //watch for changes in LastWrite
            watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastWrite;

            //event handler
            watcher.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);

            //Begin watching
            watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;


            //TCP IP SERVER
            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Waiting for 99150 to run...\n");
                //config TCP stuff
                port = 9905;
                localAddr = IPAddress.Parse("10.0.0.66");
                server = new TcpListener(localAddr, port);
                server.Start();
                client = server.AcceptTcpClient();
                stream = client.GetStream();
                Console.WriteLine("Connection to Viz successful!");
                Console.WriteLine("***LISTENING FOR CHANGES TO: " + watcher.Filter + "***\n");


            }
            catch (SocketException z)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("SocketException: {0}", z);
            }

            //prevent console from closing
            Console.ReadKey();
            Console.ReadKey();
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        // Define the event handlers.
        private static void OnChanged(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
        {
            //reload xml file
            //doc = XDocument.Load("C:/Trio Scripts/example.xml");
            //doc.Root.ReplaceWith(XElement.Load("C:/Trio Scripts/example.xml"));

            XDocument doc;
            using (var reader = XmlReader.Create("C:/Trio Scripts/example.xml"))
            {
                doc = XDocument.Load(reader);
            }

            // Nodes in XML
            string[] bans = doc.Descendants("ban").OrderBy(element => Int32.Parse(element.Attribute("order").Value)).Select(element => element.Value).ToArray();

            // String to send the message on
            String sendMsg = "";

            // Proceed with reading XML
            for (int i = 0; i < bans.Length; i++)
                sendMsg += bans[i] + " ";

            byte[] msg = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sendMsg);
            stream.Write(msg, 0, msg.Length);
            Console.WriteLine("Change detected, sending changes to Viz");
            sendMsg = "";
        }
    }//end class
}//end namespace
```

Comment: Are you using `"C:/Trio Scripts/example.xml"` file anywhere from your code? if yes post that too

Comment: FileSystemWatcher.OnChanged is called when the file is changed. Which file? and how is related to example.xml?

Comment: updated the code so you guys can see everything

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you get multiple *change events* whenever a file is changed.

You should wait a little time before reading the changed file.

Also you should use the `e.FullPath` and check the

```
 e.ChangeType == WatcherChangeTypes.Changed
```

If you fail to open the file you should *try again later*.

Comment: hmm well we're manually changing the file after a few seconds and it's still giving us that error.. as in type a couple letters.. save.. then it works the first time.. then do the same again and then we get that error

Comment: Never do any handling of the files in the change event, start a System.Threading.Task that will handle the changes.

Comment: sleep command at 10 seconds seems to work.. but that just can't cut it for what we're trying to do.  can you explain where to use that e.ChangeType == WatcherChangeTypes.Changed in our code?  sorry we're new to C#

Comment: gonna try starting a System.Threading.Task like you recommended and see if it works...

Comment: implemented the e.changetype check... still get the same error but i agree i should be using that.

Comment: implemented multithreading according to your suggestion and it works!

Answer (score 1):

You can still use `XDocument` and an `XmlReader`:

```
XDocument doc;
using (var reader = XmlReader.Create("C:/Trio Scripts/example.xml"))
{
    doc = XDocument.Load(reader);
}
```

When the `using` block completes for the reader, then the file handle should be closed.

**Update**:

Maybe the behavior of `XmlReader.Create(string)` doesn't open the file in the most minimal fashion. In case that's what's causing the exception, try this more explicit code specifying file permissions:

```
XDocument doc;
using (var stream = File.Open("C:/Trio Scripts/example.xml", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
using (var reader = XmlReader.Create(stream))
{
    doc = XDocument.Load(reader);
}
```

Comment: As a .net developer you should be deeply deeply familiar with the using statement and it's many uses.

Comment: ^ torobot we're new to C# and just learning as we go unfortunately... they just kinda threw us in it

Comment: Maybe there's another part of the code that is locking your file, perhaps the code that detects when file changes happen.

Comment: oh and in main when it loads the file... we commented that out and it still gives us the same error

Comment: Try my update. I'm not sure which line you're getting the file permissions issue for. That may be helpful to include as well (whether the stack trace points to your posted code or elsewhere).

Comment: kk will try and post back

Comment: hmm i put all the code inbetween those brackets and now getting a notsupportexception at this line: stream.Write(msg, 0, msg.Length);

Comment: Maybe not the solution for this specific question, but save my day. Thanks.